# Zotero/Betterbibtex: Isnt there any easy way to copy the info you need for the .bib file?

Tags: bibtex, zotero, better-bibtex

So im using overleaf and im trying to get Zotero to work with that. I installed the betterbibtex add-on and im trying to get this kind of code

```
@book{Strategie2030Vermogen2005,
  title = {{Strategie 2030: Verm\"ogen und Leben in der n\"achsten Generation}},
  year = {2005},
  publisher = {{HWWI}},
  address = {{Hamburg}},
  isbn = {1861-5058},
  langid = {german}
}
```

out of Zotero in my .bib file in overleaf. I found two ways to do this: right click the reference, "create bibliography from item" and then paste it in latex. That does work, but it doesn't use the cite key and format from betterbibtex, instead it uses the cite key and format from standard Zotero.

The other way is by shift-clicking and drag and drop in overleaf. For some reason this way is very buggy. Most of the time for most of the references it just doesn't work. Only thing that happens is that the cursor in overleaf freezes. When I tried it over and over with reloading and recompiling in between, it did work all of the sudden. I didnt find any pattern there. Furthermore it does work flawlessly for some references, again, I didnt find a pattern. Is that a problem you also have, or it is just me?

I found this https://github.com/dlukes/zotero-sharelatex-cayw resource, I dont quite understand if that would do what im searching for tho. Also it is for sharelatex and I dont quite understand if share latex and overleaf are the same now or not. Do you have experiences with that thing?

And yes, overleaf seems to have some Zotero features built in, but im not a paid user so that's not for me.

Any help would be great here!
Thanks!

Comment: I can't test it right now but I think `CTRL + SHIFT + C` copies a selected item to the clipboard in bib format. If that works, multiple items might also work.

Comment: Oh that's huge! Thank you!